# Receiving Swift throw-n custom error type in objective C

Tags: swift, objective-c, nserror

Im throwing an error in Swift that I'm trying to consume in ObjC. Works except when I complicate the situation by using a custom error type.

Here is the type Im throwing:

```
@objc public final class MyNetworkResponse: NSObject, Error {
...
}
```

To throw in swift Im simply doing:

```
throw resp
```

where resp is of type MyNetworkResponse.

In C resp appears to be bridged to NSError.  Im unable to convert it/cast it back to the MyNetworkResponse type - is this possible, and if so how?

Im wondering if when I declare the @objc type there is a way to override the exception type?

Comment: I should add, Im using a swift async throws function so the Objective C call looks like this:
        [self.paymentModel loadPaymentMethodsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *resp){
... }

Answer (score 1):

Errors in Objective-C are always assumed to be `NSError` objects and thus Swift automatically translated them. You can control how this is done by implementing the [CustomNSError protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/customnserror), but you will still end up with a new object, an `NSError`. You cannot cast an `NSError` to your object.

But, you can somewhat work around it. One idea:

- Implement `CustomNSError` on your `MyNetworkResponse`. In the [`errorUserInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/customnserror/3017373-erroruserinfo) you can basically put in whatever info your object holds.
- Implement `MyNetworkResponse.init?(nsError: NSError)` which looks at an `NSError` instance and tries to convert it back to your object. Check the error domain, then grab your data from the `userInfo` dictionary.

There's several variations, come up with whatever suits you, but the basic gist is that you need to put your error infos into the `NSError`'s `userInfo`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  Im grateful you confirmed what I'd found.  Re the options:  In order for them to work I will have to change all the swift to look in userInfo as well for the object it actually wants.  And change the throw calls to `throw resp.error`.  Might abandon throw and just return the object I need. :(